# Retrieve a list of usernames from Users table by searching within radius of a GeoPoint through API in Backendless

Tags: android, backendless, geopoints

In my Users table I created a field [current_location] of type GeoPoint that I use for saving their current location of the user at time (s)he logins in the app.

I would like to search within radius (let's say 10 Miles) of these Geopoint records in Users table and return the usernames of all Users within the area.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can first find GeoPoints in radius, the code samples are here: https://backendless.com/documentation/geo/android/geo_radius_based_search.htm
And then find the Users with the query like "where current_location.objectId IN (foundGeoPointId1, foundGeoPointId2)". Related docs and code samples here: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_relations_retrieve.htm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try it